# How to restore pernamently deleted google drive files

Tags: google-drive-api, delete-file, restore

There were a bunch of people in my class making a story.

Since I was the only one with coding computer knowledge, someone decided to frame me by permanently deleting the story and it's back up copies.

Along with that, the person remained anonymous (most likely by selecting Do not share my edit history with others).

Is there any way I can restore this deleted google drive file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a G Suite administrator, you can restore them by following the steps below:

1. Sign in to your Google Admin console.
   Sign in using your administrator account (does not end in @gmail.com).
2. From the Admin console Home page, go to Appsand thenG Suiteand thenDrive and Docs.
3. Click Manage shared drives.
4. To the right of the shared drive name, click Restore Restore.
5. Select a date range for the data restore. If you're restoring a shared drive and want to restore all the files that were in the shared drive when it was deleted, you must select the date it was deleted up to the current date.
   Important: You can only restore items that were removed from the shared drive's trash within the last 25 days unless you have additional Google Vault policies in place. For details, see Use Vault to search Google Drive.
6. Click Restore Data.

As I said, **this is only possible as administrator**, a normal Google account doesn't have a way to recover the files unless they are still in the trash folder. More information [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7376096?hl=en)